# How to 'show more' rows using *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have the following code (simplified in head - not tested)

```
<div class="table">
  <div *ngFor="let item of list" class="row">
    {{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="more = !more">{{ more ? 'less':'more' }}</button>
```

I want to show only the first 3 list items at the beginning - and when user clicks "more", I want to show all the list items. How to do it?

### UPDATE

More details about performance for this case are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330025/is-there-a-difference-between-using-slice-in-ngfor-directly-or-by-pipe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331157/which-approach-for-ngfor-is-better-ng-container-or-pipe-slice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach using the [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe):

```html
<div class="table">
  <div *ngFor="let item of list | slice:0:(more ? undefined : 3)" class="row">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="more = !more">{{ more ? 'less':'more' }}</button>
```

Also, use `of` instead of `in` with `*ngFor`.

Comment: instead pipe `|` we can use slice directly:  `let item of list.slice(0, more ? undefined : 3)` - so I wonder - is pipe worse/better ? (I ask question about performance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59330025/860099))

Comment: The main difference is, that `.slice()` is a function call that may be be executed when ever the change detection is triggered, while the `SlicePipe` is pure. This means, it's only executed, when the passed parameters change. Therefore I'd recommend to avoid calling methods (or using getters) inside of templates, since they may have a massive performance impact the larger the app becomes. [Here's an article on that topic](https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp) and the [angular docs about pure pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes).

Comment: add this comment as answer to question in link I provide in my previous comment

Answer (score 5):

You can use [slicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) to create a new array containing a subset an array.

```html
<div class="table">
  <div *ngFor="let item of (more ? list : (list|slice:0:3))" class="row">
      {{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}
  <div>
</div>

<button (click)="more = !more">{{ more ? 'less' : 'more' }}</button>
```

Comment: instead pipe `|` we can use slice directly:  `let item of more ? list : list.slice:(0,3)` - so I wonder - is pipe worse/better ? (I ask question about performance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59330025/860099))

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ng-container>` (which will not create any additional nodes) as follows

```html
<div class="table">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list; index as i">
    <div *ngIf="i<3 || more" class="row">
      {{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  <ng-container>
</div>

<button (click)="more = !more">{{ more ? 'less':'more' }}</button>
```