# Is there a difference between using slice in *ngFor directly or by pipe?

Tags: angular

I want to conditionally (`more=true/false`) show 3 elements of list or full list using slice pipe

```html
<div class="table">
  <div *ngFor="let item of list|slice:0:(more ? undefined : 3 )" class="row">
      {{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}
  <div>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- alternative form -->

<div class="table">
  <div *ngFor="let item of (more ? list : list|slice:0:3)" class="row">
      {{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}
  <div>
</div>
```

but I can use `slice` directly (without pipe)

```html
<div class="table">
  <div *ngFor="let item of list.slice(0,more ? undefined : 3)" class="row">
      {{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}
  <div>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- alternative form -->

<div class="table">
  <div *ngFor="let item of (more ? list : list.slice(0,3) )" class="row">
      {{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}
  <div>
</div>
```

Both solutions works. Is there a performance difference between them?

### UPDATE

More about this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59329628/860099)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>The main difference is, that `.slice()` is a function call that may be be executed when ever the change detection is triggered, while the `SlicePipe` is pure. This means, it's only executed, when the passed parameters change.</s>

Therefore I'd recommend to avoid calling methods (or using getters) inside of templates, since they may have a massive performance impact the larger the app becomes. Here's an [article on that topic](https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp) and the [angular docs about pure pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes).

The first part is not true, as a [Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321016/alex-k) mentioned, since the `SlicePipe` is impure. Thus, there won't be a noticeable difference.

Though it's bad practice to use functions or getters inside of templates (as long as you're not following the `OnPush` change detection strategy), the better way would be to put the logic for slicing the array inside the components controller.

Comment: Agree, I'll even go a step further and say, do the logic in your component and have as little "logic" in your template as possible

Comment: @c_ogoo - do you see alternative solution of such list view - I mean: move `array slice` logic out of the templete? If yes then put you answer into [THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59329628/860099)

Answer (score 2):

The `slicePipe` and `Array.slice()` behave differently in an Angular expression.

The `slicePipe` will not trigger a template error for `undefined` or `null` values, and if a value is the wrong type then an `invalidPipeArgumentError` error is thrown.

When you call `Array.slice()` on an `undefined` value, then you raise `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`. If you call `slice()` on an invalid type, then you raise `ERROR TypeError: value.slice is not a function`.

You can suppress the `undefined` error by using the `?` operator, for example; `Array?.slice(...)`, but this requires the developer to remember to always do this.

The above is an important distinction, because `*ngFor` accepts `undefined` and `null` values as valid. For example; `<div *ngFor="let i of null"></div>` does not raise an error.

They both perform at the same speed. The web browser is your performance bottleneck with `*ngFor`, because it takes far longer to insert DOM elements. If you're using an array of 1000 items, then calling `slice()` or `slicePipe()` is not going to have any measurable difference, but you're going to see how slow the web browser is when updating the DOM. So you'll gain better performance by making fewer changes to your array.